# check in api foursquare

Tags: foursquare, checkin

I wanted to find out the number of check-in counts for some regions of Manhattan (eg, for each zip code), in 2 weeks, and I wanted it to be classified into 24 hours a day.
Does anyone know if it is possible and if yes how can I do that?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/

Answer (score 1):

Only venue managers (if you own the venue) can get fine-grade check-in information via the Merchant Platform API: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/merchants

API call/example: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/stats

Armansu asked the same question here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/foursquare-api/5k6lzRwJFjA